# How to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage using Drone.io

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, drone.io

I have a *.deb file* as my project artifact. I would like to know how upload it to Azure Blob Storage using Drone.io!

Comment: There is a go sdk for blob storage: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/storage-blob-go-getting-started/

Comment: Also found a plugin on github, you may have a look at the code: https://github.com/drone-plugins/drone-azure-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the official documentation: http://readme.drone.io/0.4/plugins/azure_storage/
They provided a sample on how to do that:

```
 publish:
  azure_storage:
    account_key: 123889asd89u8hsfdjh98128hh
    storage_account: my-storage-account
    container: my-storage-container
    source: folder/to/upload
```

It's a storage plugin specifically made for Azure. Let me know if this helps.